# Origine/étymologie de l’expression « Trop fort ! »

Tags: expressions, origine-ou-raison

Pour répondre à [une question sur un autre site (Spanish Stack Exchange)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16789/de-d%C3%B3nde-viene-la-expresi%C3%B3n-qu%C3%A9-fuerte), j’ai cherché l’origine de l’expression « *¡Qué fuerte!* », qui est souvent utilisée pour exprimer la surprise. Comme je ne trouvais rien, j’ai fait ce que je fais d’habitude, quand je veux connaître l’étymologie d’un terme : le comparer avec d'autres langues romanes. Alors j’ai pensé à l’expression italienne « Che forte! » et à l’expression française « Trop fort ! », mais elles sont utilisées de manière différente, notamment pour dire que quelque chose est « fantastique » ou « génial ». Cette acception, bien que différente de l’expression espagnole, est aussi intéressante, car elle exprime une idée qui n’est pas intrinsèque au sens plus évident du terme *fort*. Alors :

- Sait-on quand *fort* a commencé à être utilisé avec le sens de « génial » et quelle peut en être la raison (c’est-à-dire, la relation avec le sens original) ?
- Si ce n’est pas hors-sujet, sait-on s'il y a une relation entre l’expression italienne « che forte » et l'expression française ?

---

Note : ci-dessous  la description de l’expression italienne  « che forte! » :

> Q: I was recently playing an online card game with an Italian player. After he won the first game and before we began the second game, he said "cavoli che forte". Can anyone translate this for me?
>
> A1: Damn, this is good!
> A2: Holy cow, that's cool!!
>
> [WordReference](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/cavoli-che-forte.1888978/)

<sub>Here goes my first question in French, I hope I haven't made many mistakes!</sub>

See also [the same question on Italian Stack Exchange](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/6982/etimologia-origine-dellespressione-che-forte).

Comment: "Here goes my first question in French, I hope I haven't made many mistakes!" Pas du tout, pour un premier essai c'est un coup de maître!

Answer (score 2):

Il est difficile de reconstruire l'étymologie d'une expression qui est exclusivement orale ou presque. Je vais donc proposer une hypothèse, sans preuves.

Je pense qu'il s'agit d'une suite logique de l'histoire du mot *fort*. En latin, *fortis* a déjà beaucoup de sens: grand, important, robuste, vigoureux, vertueux... En français, certains de ces sens ont disparu et d'autres sont apparus. En particulier, *fort* peut signifier non seulement la force physique, mais aussi une grande capacité dans n'importe quel domaine : habileté, intelligence, etc. ([TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fort) III.A.1). Au départ, *fort* est une qualité de quelqu'un (« il est fort aux échecs ») ; par métonymie, on peut aussi l'utiliser pour une action qui montre que quelqu'un est fort (TLF III.A.1.a) (« son jeu d'échec est fort »). En particulier, quelque chose de *trop fort* est quelque chose qui montre que quelqu'un est plus fort que ce à quoi on pourrait s'attendre.

Mon hypothèse est que ce sens a évolué : « c'est *trop fort* » signifie « c'est mieux que ce que j'attendais », donc « c'est très bien ». Ce sens est renforcé par une nuance qui vient d'une étymologie convergente : dire que quelque chose est « trop fort », ça sous-entend qu'on ne comprend pas comment la personne qui l'a fait a pu le faire ; cette personne est donc très (trop) forte, plus forte que la personne qui dit « trop fort ».

Comment: @L'aditdabenlà Non, je ne cherchais pas à rejoindre ce sens, mais c'est vrai que c'est plus proche, donc plus probable. Je vous invite à faire une réponse en ce sens. (Au passage, je comprends « trop fort ! », mais je ne le dis pas non plus.)

Comment: En fin de compte je penche davantage pour votre genre d'interprétation, avec _trop_ comme élément subjectif, voire comme simple exagération du sens dont vous traitez. Parce qu'il y avait un juron dans l'expression initiale, j'ai aussi pensé à un truc comme _c'est fort en maudit_, etc. Merci !

Answer (score 2):

Il y a aussi la voie de ce qui *exprime un pouvoir d'ordre intellectuel ou moral*, appliqué à une chose, et *[q]ui surprend ou choque par son caractère insolite ou excessif. Synon. exagéré, outré, inadmissible, incroyable.*, en locution familière : *C'est fort, un peu fort, trop fort* [c'est trop fort] ; *le plus fort est que; c'est un peu fort de café; c'est plus fort que de jouer au bouchon.* ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fort), III, B, 4.). DHLF/Rey (Robert) parle d'une valeur spéciale « excessif, exagéré » au 14<sup>e</sup> ; et note 1692 pour *c'est fort* dans ce sens. On parle d'un « intensif usuel » pour *(c'est) [fort de café](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fort_forte/34684/locution)*. Par ailleurs on dit *fort* pour *ce qui dépasse la normale*, par extension de *plus accentué que les autres*, comme on en traite [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/19343), sur le thème de la force comme impression (souvent pénible) d'*intensité*, milieu 16<sup>e</sup>. En résumé le premier avec la surprise, et le deuxième, avec une sémantique qu'on peut associer à *très bon, meilleur*. Enfin [*trop*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trop) peut en soi avoir valeur de superlatif pour exprimer l'*appréciation subjective* : « Ah! c'est trop con! » (Sartre, au TLFi). Intensément *incroyable* ou *excellent*, d'après l'opinion du locuteur ; ou subjectivement meilleur que la normale...